# Is the if-statement with a const condition optimized inside a for loop (c++)

Tags: c++, performance, if-statement, optimization, compiler-optimization

Consider the following code:

```
void func(int a, size_t n)
{
  const bool cond = (a==2);
  if (cond){
    for (size_t i=0; i<n; i++){
      // do something small 1
      // continue by doing something else.
    }
  } else {
    for (size_t i=0; i<n; i++){
      // do something small 2
      // continue by doing something else.
    }
  }
}
```

In this code the `// continue by doing something else.` (which might be a large part and for some reason cannot be separated into a function) is repeated exactly the same. To avoid this repetition one can write:

```
void func(int a, size_t n)
{
  const bool cond = (a==2);
  for (size_t i=0; i<n; i++){
    if (cond){
      // do something small 1
    } else {
      // do something small 2
    }
    // continue by doing something else.
  }
}
```

Now we have an if-statement inside a (let's say very large) for-loop. But the condition of the if-statement (`cond`) is const and will not change. Would the compiler somehow optimize the code (like change it to the initial implementation)? Any tips? Thanks.

Comment: Just see the assembly the compiler generates.

Comment: In this case modern compilers should be able to optimize it out. But might consider it pointless depending on methods you call inside the content. In more complex cases where the `bool` could be modified during for-loop (from compilers perspective) then it won't be able to perform such an optimization. That's being said, branch predictor ensures that it doesn't really matter.

Comment: first code misses a `}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Details do matter and you included too little. As you are asking for compiler optimizations you need to know that the compiler will optimize according to the as-if-rule. Sloppy speaking, the compiler can do any optimization as long as they do not change the observable behavior (there are few exceptions). Both your functions have zero observable behavior, hence with optimizations turned on, gcc -O3, this is what the compiler does to them:

```
func(int, unsigned long):
        ret
func2(int, unsigned long):
        ret
```

It is futile to speculate what the compiler does to your code. Don't speculate, but look at the output. You can do that here: https://godbolt.org/z/oznWz6.

PS: Some mantras that I should not forget to include:

Don't do premature optimization. Code should be written primiarily to be read by humans. Only when you profiled and have evidence that you can gain something by improving that function you may consider to trade performance for readability.

Also do not forget that code you write is not instructions for your CPU. Your code is an abstract description of what the final program should do. The compiler knows very well how to rearrange the code to get most out of your CPU. Typically it is much better at this than a human could possibly be.